# AttributeError:'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_css_selector'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

from selenium import webdriver

def scrape_coordinates(city):
# Initialize the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

```
# Open Google Maps
driver.get("https://maps.google.com")

# Find the search bar and enter the city
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[aria-label='Search Google Maps']")
search_bar.send_keys(city)
search_bar.submit()

# Wait for the map to load and find the coordinates element
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
coordinates_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".QSFF4-text")

# Get the coordinates text
coordinates_text = coordinates_element.get_attribute("textContent")
latitude, longitude = coordinates_text.split(",")

# Close the browser
driver.quit()

return latitude.strip(), longitude.strip()
```

## Get user input

city_input = input("Enter the city name to search for coordinates on Google Maps: ")

## Scrape coordinates

latitude, longitude = scrape_coordinates(city_input)

print(f"Coordinates for {city_input}: Latitude - {latitude}, Longitude - {longitude}")